# error c2400 found new line

Tags: c, assembly

Something went wrong with this code, and I'm seeking for help please

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
  __asm
  {y db 10
   format db "%s"
   mov eax, y
   add eax,1
   push eax
   push format
   call printf
   push 0x8  
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, having data in the code stream, especially first in the execution path looks like a bad thing.

Comment: If we had any hint at all about what was the "something" that went wrong, it would probably be somewhat easier to identify. But the data variable stored in the instruction stream does seem like a good place to start... But the rest of the code looks a bit ... odd ... as well, so picking out the one thing that "went wrong" is a bit of a guess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the thread will be soon on hold ("off topic"), so let me show quickly the corrected code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    char y = 10;
    char* format = "%d";

    __asm
    {
        movzx eax, y
        add eax,1
        push eax
        push format
        call printf
        add esp, 8
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well done.  Although to elaborate you normally cannot declare variables in inline assembly since the assembly is places into the .text or .code segment of the binary executable.  Compared to the .data or .bss segments in which data is placed.  Placing the variable declarations outside of the inline assembly will allow them to be placed into the correct section of the binary.